# Veryifying the Collatz Conjecture for one number without explicit computation

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Basically the title. Exhaustive computer searches are going on all the time, but if we seem to find a very large counterexample to the Collatz Conjecture, how will we ever know that it doesn't, in the end, hit $1$? Are there any results, theorems, or algorithms that can help us here?

Comment: An obvious possibility is that it has been found that $n \to \cdots \to n,$ i.e. there is a cycle not including $1$.

Comment: Welcome to the Collatz game :)  Might I recommend a book? "The Ultimate Challenge: The 3x+1 Problem", edited by Jeff Lagarias, compiles most known results on this topic.

Comment: Counterexamples come with a proof that they are counterexamples.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter How? If the number just keeps getting larger and never hits a cycle...

Comment: In theory one could hope to prove that the iterates of $n$ never get below $n$.  The least counterexample would certainly have that property.

Comment: This is part of what makes the problem difficult. Of course, if we find a loop other than 1-4-2-1, then just listing that loop, or even a single number in that loop, is enough to allow anyone else to confirm. However, if the number just gives a diverging sequence, I don't think anyone knows what a proof of such a divergence could possibly be. Modular arithmetic, for instance, is uncharacteristically unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Are there any results, theorems, or algorithms that can help us here?"
Perhaps the following is interesting if not helpful: 
if there really is a nontrivial cycle in the Collatz problem, then $\det M (d) = 0$ for all large $d$, but if there are none then $\det M (d) = (−1)^d$ for all $d$. Here $M(d)$ is Zeilberger's matrix.

References: [Chapman](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0b8b/7f823a5ed96b7e889cf76fede9a178f41517.pdf)

[Zeilberger's determinant evaluation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633939/zeilbergers-determinant-evaluation-problem)

Comment: Hmm, I think this is a simple (or even complicated) "blow-up" of the original problem (see Chapman's proof) and thus surely not really *helpful* .

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yes, I just found it interesting. "Helpful" here, it seems from the comments, is not really available in this context (but "unhelpful" is).

Comment: Dietrich - thanks for your reflection. Actually, my comment might be enough for what should to be said; I've been courious enough to follow your links and to experiment a bit with that matrix - "one nice idea" I must say ... . I'm now deeply involved in another problem so I just want to respond shortly that I don't want to make a big problem. Happy new year to all, btw. - Gottfried

Answer (score 0):

You're touching upon the notion that the conjecture may be unprovable within certain mathematical systems. This does indeed follow from your observation that one counterexample could ascend indefinitely to infinity.

If a theory weren't strong enough, any proof that some infinitely long sequence exists might itself not be writable in a finite number of steps, making such a proof impossible to complete.